# How to format date to "2018-10-29 11:49:33"

Tags: perl, datetime

I have to convert the GMT date to region specific date with format like "YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S". 
**Code developed is :-**

```
use Time::Local;

($year,$mon,$day) = split /\-/, $ARGV[0];
($hrs,$min,$sec ) = split /:/, $ARGV[1];
$time = timegm( $sec, $min, $hrs, $day, $mon-1, $year-1900);
print scalar localtime($time), "\n";
```

But when I run it like :-

```
$ perl testDateGMTToLocal.pl 2018-10-29 11:49:33
```

It gives o/p converted in local time zone:-

```
Mon Oct 29 07:49:33 2018
```

But I want this o/p in below format

```
29-OCT-18 07:49:33
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Time::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Format) looks promising. Or there's [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html), which provides `strftime()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to do it all using modules. The all-capable and very complete module is [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime), and for this job you'd also need [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime).

One other option is the simpler and much smaller core module [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

die "Usage $0 YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S" if @ARGV != 2;
my $time = join ' ', @ARGV;

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($time, "%Y-%m-%d %T");

my $local = localtime($tp->epoch);

say $local;

# In the desired format
say join('-', $local->mday, uc $local->month, $local->yy),
    ' ', $local->hms;

# If "Oct" is ok instead of block capitals for month abbreviation
say $local->strftime("%d-%b-%y %T");
```

This converts GMT time, with invocation as in the question, to the local time on my machine

```
Mon Oct 29 04:09:33 2018
29-OCT-18 04:09:33
29-Oct-18 04:09:33
```

where the middle one was asked for.

On some systems there is the `%F` format specifier for `%Y-%m-$d`.<sup>†</sup> There may be a defined format for `29-OCT-18`, in which case you don't have to patch it by hand, but I am not aware of it.

---

<sup>†</sup> Or the module has its own formatting in which case that's portable. But origin of the error when it fails to do `%F` on my system isn't clear to me in that sense.

Comment: Re "*On some systems*", Time::Piece uses its own formatting engine, so it's not system-sensitive.

Comment: @ikegami  On my system (CentOS 7, v5.16) the `%F` isn't recognized: the module dies with a parsing error, at a line with `_strptime` which I can only trace to `Dynaloader`.  It seems like it is using the system for that?

Comment: Maybe it only uses its own implementation of `strftime` as a fallback? That's not what I was told. Leaving that comment so you can keep your reply.

Comment: @ikegami In my copy, the `sub strptime` in `/usr/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm` directly goes to `_strptime`; same with `strftime`.  I don't know what `Dynaload` loads though, but I'd guess that it isn't module's own C code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

print(strftime("%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S", localtime($time)), "\n");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, You really think adding "you can use `strftime`" before showing they can use `strftime` is useful? No. That's just patronising noise. Just like excessive comments can be detrimental, so can redundant explanations

Comment: @IanLim, huh? Check again

Comment: Not enough explanation

Comment: @Ian Lim, That's not what you original comment said. And that's not a constructive comment. What's missing?